# Columns and rows not calculating

Tags: c, windows

I have written a program to display a two dimensional array and calculate the totals of both the columns and rows. Initially when compiling I got the error "uninitialized local error" for both `total1` and `total2`. I then set the value for both equal to 0 and then the total also became zero. I have attached the code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
int main()
{

#define NUMROWS 5
#define NUMCOLS 5
    int val[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = { 8,3,9,0,10,
                                3,5,17,1,1,
                                2,8,6,23,1,
                                15,7,3,2,9,
                                6,14,2,6,0 };

    int total1, total2, sumrow1, sumrow2, sumrow3, sumrow4, sumrow5, sumcol1, sumcol2, sumcol3, sumcol4, sumcol5;
    total1 = 0;
    total2 = 0;

    printf("\n Enter row 1: %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d", val[0][0], val[0][1], val[0][2], val[0][3], val[0][4]);
    printf("\n Enter row 2: %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d", val[1][0], val[1][1], val[1][2], val[1][3], val[1][4]);
    printf("\n Enter row 3: %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d", val[2][0], val[2][1], val[2][2], val[2][3], val[2][4]);
    printf("\n Enter row 4: %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d", val[3][0], val[3][1], val[3][2], val[3][3], val[3][4]);
    printf("\n Enter row 5: %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d", val[4][0], val[4][1], val[4][2], val[4][3], val[4][4]);

    printf("\n Row totals: %2d", total1);

    sumrow1 = val[0][0] + val[0][1] + val[0][2] + val[0][3] + val[0][4];
    sumrow2 = val[1][0] + val[1][1] + val[1][2] + val[1][3] + val[1][4];
    sumrow3 = val[2][0] + val[2][1] + val[2][2] + val[2][3] + val[2][4];
    sumrow4 = val[3][0] + val[3][1] + val[3][2] + val[3][3] + val[3][4];
    sumrow5 = val[4][0] + val[4][1] + val[4][2] + val[4][3] + val[4][4];

    total1 = total1 + sumrow1 + sumrow2 + sumrow3 +sumrow4 + sumrow5;

    printf("\n Colum totals: %2d", total2);

    sumcol1 = val[0][0] + val[0][1] + val[0][2] + val[0][3] + val[0][4];
    sumcol2 = val[1][0] + val[1][1] + val[1][2] + val[1][3] + val[1][4];
    sumcol3 = val[2][0] + val[2][1] + val[2][2] + val[2][3] + val[2][4];
    sumcol4 = val[3][0] + val[3][1] + val[3][2] + val[3][3] + val[3][4];
    sumcol5 = val[4][0] + val[4][1] + val[4][2] + val[4][3] + val[4][4];

    total2 = total2 + sumcol1 + sumcol2 + sumcol3 + sumcol4 + sumcol5;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at where your printf calls are relative to the math you're doing.  Add first, print second.

Comment: First you need to do addition, then you can print its current value. keep your `printf` line after performing addition.

Comment: I feel a little silly now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If that's the worst you ever do you'll still be ahead of most people, including me. :)  I find that stepping through new code in a debugger points out all sorts of silly things, plus knowing how to use a debugger is always a useful skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code :

```
printf("\n Row totals: %2d", total1);

sumrow1 = val[0][0] + val[0][1] + val[0][2] + val[0][3] + val[0][4];
sumrow2 = val[1][0] + val[1][1] + val[1][2] + val[1][3] + val[1][4];
sumrow3 = val[2][0] + val[2][1] + val[2][2] + val[2][3] + val[2][4];
sumrow4 = val[3][0] + val[3][1] + val[3][2] + val[3][3] + val[3][4];
sumrow5 = val[4][0] + val[4][1] + val[4][2] + val[4][3] + val[4][4];

total1 = total1 + sumrow1 + sumrow2 + sumrow3 +sumrow4 + sumrow5;
```

actually prints `total1` first and then computes it again. As long as you have initialized it to `0`, it will print `zero`.

If you want to print the new value of `total1`, add the `printf` statement ***below*** your calculations, like this :

```
sumrow1 = val[0][0] + val[0][1] + val[0][2] + val[0][3] + val[0][4];
sumrow2 = val[1][0] + val[1][1] + val[1][2] + val[1][3] + val[1][4];
sumrow3 = val[2][0] + val[2][1] + val[2][2] + val[2][3] + val[2][4];
sumrow4 = val[3][0] + val[3][1] + val[3][2] + val[3][3] + val[3][4];
sumrow5 = val[4][0] + val[4][1] + val[4][2] + val[4][3] + val[4][4];

total1 = total1 + sumrow1 + sumrow2 + sumrow3 +sumrow4 + sumrow5;
printf("\n Row totals: %2d", total1);
```

The same applies for `total2` as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could be useful

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUMROWS 5
#define NUMCOLS 5

int main()
{

    int i,j,a=0;
    int total1=0,total2=0;

    int val[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = { 8,3,9,0,10,
                            3,5,17,1,1,
                            2,8,6,23,1,
                            15,7,3,2,9,
                            6,14,2,6,0 };

    printf("Given Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUMROWS;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<NUMCOLS;j++)
            printf("%3d",val[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n\nSum of Coloums:\n");

    for(i=0;i<NUMROWS;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<NUMCOLS;j++)
            a=a+ val[i][j];

        total1=total1 + a;
        printf("sumrow%d=%3d",i+1,a);
        a=0;
    }

    printf("\n\nSum of Rows:\n");

    for(i=0;i<NUMROWS;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<NUMCOLS;j++)   
             a=a+ val[j][i];

        total2=total2 +a;
        printf("sumcol%d=%3d",i+1,a);
        a=0;
    }

    printf("\n\ntotal1:%d",total1);
    printf("\n\ntotal2:%d",total2);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem - as mentioned already - is that you want to access the value of a variable that is not initialized yet. In order to fix this, initialize the variable. In your case you did the printing before calculating the value. In order to see those errors at compile time, tell your compiler that you want to see every warning. For gcc you can do this by adding the `-Wall` argument. If you want to compile the `main.c` you should do something like `gcc -Wall main.c`.

Apart from that I would highly recommend to use for-loops in combination with arrays. This reduces the amount of code you have to write and makes the code more general. Let's say you want to use a 6x6 array instead of the 5x5 array. Then you would have to modify the whole code you wrote so far. When using for-loops this is not the case.

I modified your program such that it prints out the value of the 2D-array, calculates the sum of each row and col and prints those out as well. This has been implemented using for-loops. I added as much comments as I thought were necessary; if you don't understand a certain part just ask :)

```
#include<stdio.h> // include this to use printf

#define NUMROWS 5
#define NUMCOLS 5


int main(void)
{
    int val[NUMROWS][NUMCOLS] = { // initialize a 2D-array this way {{row1}, {row2}, ..}
        {8,3,9,0,10},
        {3,5,17,1,1},
        {2,8,6,23,1},
        {15,7,3,2,9},
        {6,14,2,6,0}
    };

    int sumRow[NUMROWS] = { 0 }; // initialize with 0   
    int sumCol[NUMCOLS] = { 0 }; // initialize with 0

    int i; // i = row
    int j; // j = col
    for(i = 0; i < NUMROWS; i++) { // iterate through the array and print out the values and generate the sumRow and sumCol
        printf("Enter row %d:", i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < NUMCOLS; j++) { // loop through a row 
            sumRow[i] += val[i][j]; // update the sumRow value for this row
            sumCol[j] += val[i][j]; // update the sumCol value for this col
            printf(" %2d", val[i][j]); // print out the current value of row i and col j
        }
        printf(" => %2d\n", sumRow[i]); // print the sumRow for the current row
    }
    printf("            ");
    for(j = 0; j < NUMCOLS; j++) { // loop through the col
        printf(" %2d", sumCol[j]); // print the sumCol for the current col
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Generated console output

```
Enter row 1:  8  3  9  0 10 => 30
Enter row 2:  3  5 17  1  1 => 27
Enter row 3:  2  8  6 23  1 => 40
Enter row 4: 15  7  3  2  9 => 36
Enter row 5:  6 14  2  6  0 => 28
             34 37 37 32 21
```